# constructing new genereating set for $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Is it true that $S_n$ is generated by the transposition $(12)$ and the set of $3$-cycles $\{(123),(124),\dots ,(12n)\}$ according to the splitting lemma of $Z_2$ and $A_n$?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Is $(123\dots n)\in \langle\{(12), (123),\dots, (12n)\}\rangle$, the subgroup of $S_n$ generated by the given set?

*Click, hover over, or tap the box below for more.*

> Yes.